# MYSQL case sensitive search (using hibernate) for utf8

Tags: mysql, authentication, hql, case-sensitive

I have Login Table that have utf8 charset and utf8 collation when I want check user name and retrieve other information for this specific user name the hql query give me the same result with lowercase and uppercase.
what should l do for my HQL query that work case sesitive
I use Mysql 5 and java hibernarte

this is my query:

```
return queryManager.executeQueryUniqueResult("select b.login from BranchEntity b where b.userName = ?", username);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your column's definition to use case-insensitive collation like `utf8_bin`.

Details are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: it seems work for me but must test more, tanx if it work fine I marked it.

Answer (score 2):

Add class

```
public class CollateDialect extends MySQLDialect {
    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " COLLATE utf8_bin";
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.kriyak.hbm.CollateDialect");
```

this will make all queries case-sensitive that makes much more sence.

Comment: This seems to make the column names case-sensitive, too. But Hibernate can live with it and so can I.

Comment: also if you do that it may not set the InnoDB or MyISAM correctly.