# MariaDB / MySQL querys are case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, case, mariadb

I just want to know if that querys are case sensitive or not. Are the same these querys?

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login="john";
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login="John";
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login="JOHN";
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login="jOHn";
```

I have tried that on my console and all of them worked, but I want to be sure of that if I would use Hibernate or anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: If only there was some way we could find out.

Comment: I had the same question in my mind, Later I thought to give a try in my setup. Result is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282529/1131607

Comment: I've seen so many comments like this on stackoverflow.  The pattern of such comments is (sometimes sarcastically or scoldingly) "why don't you just try it and see"?  Is that the purpose of stackoverflow?  Here, the OP even said that they tried it and it worked.  They're looking for someone knowledgeable to [dis]agree or clarify the situation.  I think that's a valid question for stackoverflow.  I've become rather tired of seeing condescending comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html),

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and
>   latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case
>   insensitive by default

As to the second part of you question - [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256001/mysql-case-sensitive-search-using-hibernate-for-utf8) shows you how to configure to have the searchers be case sensitive.

Comment: Could be a good idea use functions like: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login=LOWER("john") ?

Comment: In newer versions of MySQL, the defaults changed to `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci`.  In both cases, the `_ci` means "case (and accent) insensitive".  In your query, this applies to the column `login`.

Comment: If you have the collation set correctly, don't bother with `LOWER()`.

Answer (score 1):

From [MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-case-sensitivity/), it depends on OS. For Windows, it's not case-sensitive. For Linux, Database, table, table aliases and trigger names are affected by the systems case-sensitivity, while index, column, column aliases, stored routine and event names are never case sensitive.

Comment: I checked now in my MariaDB, but it seems not case sensitive (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282529/1131607)

Comment: This is not true. I'm on GNU/Linux and our legacy MyISAM tables have their collation set as `utf8_bin`. Thus, search is case sensitive. I need to do `LOWER(column_name)` when searching for some value e.g. `europe` and not `Europe`
Example:
`WHERE LOWER(comment) REGEXP 'picopsu|pico-psu'`
So it all depends on the collation of the table and not OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example from my Linux ( Debian 10 ) Box in MariaDB (Ver.10.3.18-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 ).May be helpful for someone !!

```
MariaDB [niffdb]> select * from account_heads where head_desc="Fuel";
+---------+-----------+
| head_id | head_desc |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Fuel      |
+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.004 sec)

MariaDB [niffdb]> select * from account_heads where head_desc="FUEL";
+---------+-----------+
| head_id | head_desc |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Fuel      |
+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [niffdb]> select * from account_heads where head_desc="fUEL";
+---------+-----------+
| head_id | head_desc |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Fuel      |
+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [niffdb]>
```